# Crear una foreign key en phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Necesito crear una foreign key en una base de datos que tengo en phpmyadmin. La base de datos está formada por 4 tablas, todas ellas ya contienen datos. Una de las tres tablas se relaciona con el resto de ellas. Todas las columnas de la tabla principal tienen un índice pero aparece un error al intentar crear las foreign keys.
Alguna solución?

Este es el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: porfavor pon una imagen del error y/o de tus tablas para que asi podamos ayudarte... saludos

Comment: En tu tabla, presiona la opción de estructura, después vista de relaciones y ahí está la opción.

Comment: En vistas de relaciones es precisamente donde está el error. El error es: [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rug3U.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rug3U.png) Gracias

Comment: Para crea una llave foranea en tablas que ya tienen datos debes asegurarte que el campo que estara en la tabla padre tenga exactamento los mismos datos que estan en el campo de la tabla hija. ya que de lo contrario no puedes tener un campo hijo sin su padre por asi decirlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bueno como dice el error tienes que verificar que los datos que estas ingresando sean correctos, específicamente el campo ID_ESTADO, tienes que colocar un ID_ESTADO que se encuentre en la tabla ANEXO de lo contrario no vas a poder hacer el insert ya que se está verificando que exista el mismo.

Comment: Marca la pregunta como solucionada.